# Missing log statements in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, logging

I have a java GAE application running, in which i make several log statements. 
I log the statements like this:

```
  Logger log = Logger.getLogger(...class.getName());

  log.info("status: " + status);
```

and have set the logginlevel to .level = INFO in the loggin.properties.xml.

This is an example of what i se the the console:

```
 {
   metadata: {…}  
    protoPayload: {…}  
   insertId: "2016-09-27|07:52:50.372995-07|10.106.9.209|-787832401"   
   log: "appengine.googleapis.com/request_log"   
    httpRequest: {
        status: 200    
             }
    operation: {
    id:                             064be687375a060001737e6c61676b61676568757365742d636c69636b2d616e642d636f6c6c6563         74000131000100"    
     producer: "appengine.googleapis.com/request_id"    
     }
  }
```

Sadly i cant see the logstatements in the console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer.
Am i missing something? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AE Flexible? Try looking at the "All logs" or specifically in "app" log.

Comment: No just the standard GAE enviroment, nad ive tried that. I think i see all the 'request_logs', but my own log statements are not to be found.

Comment: BTW, is "loggin.properties.xml" a typo or a real file? It should be "logging.properties". See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/logs/ for name and location.